# Google Sheet AppScript: Show range name of a changed cell

Tags: google-apps-script

```html
    function onEdit(e) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var currentCell = e.range.getA1Notation();
    Browser.msgBox(currentCell);
    }
```

With this script I can display the row and column of a changed cell value (like A1, B12, F30).

But is it also possible to show the name of a changed cell. The cell name I set up as an "named range". Instead of showing B20 I want to display "CARS" (card is the named range of cell B20.

I tried many variations of **getRangeByName** witout luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a cell is edited, you want to show the name of the named range using `Browser.msgBox` of the edited cell.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please edit a cell. By this, the script is automatically run by the simple trigger of OnEdit.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const namedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  if (namedRanges.length == 0) return;
  const f = namedRanges.find(o => {
    const r = o.getRange();
    const startRow = r.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startCol = r.getColumn();
    const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    return startRow <= range.rowStart && endRow >= range.rowEnd && startCol <= range.columnStart && endCol >= range.columnEnd;
  });
  Browser.msgBox(f ? f.getName() : range.getA1Notation());
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained. You can see the dialog including the name of the named range of the edited cell.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to show the dialog only when the cells of the named range are edited, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      Browser.msgBox(f ? f.getName() : range.getA1Notation());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (f) Browser.msgBox(f.getName());
    ```

#### References:

- [getNamedRanges() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getnamedranges)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)